# Where has the iOS private GAIA.framework been moved too? (that contained the OSDBattery class)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Does anyone know what replaces or where to find the OSDBattery equivalent that was previously in the now missing in iOS 7 private framework "GAIA.framework". Several non-app store battery utilities relied on that detailed information and I have even examined my iPhone5's private frameworks (iOS v7.0.6) and came up with nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/batterystatus/introduction/intro.html

Also: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: +1 UIDevice battery metrics may be all I have to fall back on at this time. I'll keep this open for a while longer in hopes of getting an answer to where OSDBattery has been moved too since the GAIA framework that was present in iOS 6.x is no longer present. OSDBattery provides much more detail about battery that I am trying to get at. Mostly yo get a cleaner less 'stair step' graph. As shown in this project:
[BatteryChart on GitHub](https://github.com/nst/BatteryChart)
edit: submitted before putting the link in

Comment: I think this is the answer until someone discovers where OSDBattery was moved to or something equivalent.